# What math operation comes after exponentiation (^)?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, operation, exponentiation

Let's give expressions some names:

```
x+3 = x+1+1+1 // lvl 1
x*3 = x+x+x   // lvl 2
x^3 = x*x*x   // lvl 3
```

**What would be** the mathematical ***term / real name / topic*** for **lvl**s after 3?

Like:

```
x (lvl 4 operation) 3 = x^x^x
x (lvl 5 operation) 3 = x(lvl 4 operation)x(lvl 4 operation)x
..
```

Thanks in advance.

*P.S. Above are not programming codes/languages*

Comment: How is this a Haskell problem?

Comment: Check out the original three argument [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)!

Comment: as a note `n! ~ n^n`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics and not programming. See also [this Math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/489705).

Comment: @pigworker: interesting, thanks for that!

Comment: There's also [Up Arrow Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)

Comment: @Lol4t0: False! `n^n / n!` grows without bound as `n` increases.

Comment: @duplode this is about algorithm solution clarity.

Comment: @Alois Mahdal: much of lambda expression stuff, i know haskellers have much higher probability to know the answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) is the next [hyperoperator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) after exponentiation. The operator is noted as `↑↑` — or `^^` in ASCII — following [Knuth's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation).

The next operation in the sequence is [pentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentation), then [hexation](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hexation), heptation, octation, etc. [Ackermann's three-argument function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) calculates these operations recursively.

```
╭────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────────╮
│  Level │     Name       │  Notation   │ Ackermann (3-arg) │
╞════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════════╡   
│    1   │   Successor    │ a++ (unary) │   φ(a, 1, 0)      │
│    2   │   Addition     │ a+b         │   φ(a, b, 0)      │
│    3   │ Multiplication │ a×b         │   φ(a, b, 1)      │ 
│    4   │ Exponentiation │ a↑b         │   φ(a, b, 2)      │
│    5   │   Pentation    │ a↑↑b        │   φ(a, b, 3)      │
│    6   │   Hexation     │ a↑↑↑b       │   φ(a, b, 4)      │
│    7   │   Heptation    │ a↑↑↑↑b      │   φ(a, b, 5)      │
│    8   │   Octation     │ a↑↑↑↑↑b     │   φ(a, b, 6)      │
╰────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────╯
```

Answer (score 3):

There aren't really any general operations beyond exponentiation (primarily due to a lack of need). One possible extension is [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), which abbreviates a stack of exponents with the same value. In brief (using 
[Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)

```
a ^^ 1 = a
a ^^ n = a^(a^^(n-1))
       = a ^ a ^ ... ^ a  (n items)
```

Up-arrow notation can itself be stacked, with `a^^^a` being a stack of `a`s `a^^a` high, `a^^^^a` a stack `a^^^a` high, etc. (The numbers created are comically large; read about [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) to find out just how large a number you can build.)

Answer (score 3):

One way to make this a Haskell question is to set the challenge of implementing the Ackermann function (whichever version) in terms of the "paramorphism" for natural numbers, represented here via `Integer`, and no other form of recursion.

```
paraNat :: t -> ((Integer, t) -> t) -> Integer -> t
paraNat base step n | n > 0 = step (m, paraNat base step m) where m = n - 1
paraNat base step _         = base
```

It's a well known fact that "paramorphism" corresponds to "primitive recursion", and it's another well known fact that Ackermann's function is not in the class of "primitive recursive functions". And yet, the problem has a solution. The clue is that `paraNat` is polymorphic in its return type `t`, whereas the class of "primitive recurisve functions" fixes `t` to be the natural numbers.

(I realise it's a touch unorthodox to answer a question by posing a question, but I hope it's interesting anyway. I'll delete this answer if folk think it's problematic.)

Comment: funny, but i've reinvented the pure copy of Ackermann function today, and that made me wonder if it actually existed before ;d
Haskell totally equals love

Comment: You can also do it without polymorphism.